# How can you export WiFi settings from Windows 7 to an Apple Mac OSX?

Tags: windows-7, macos, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-transfer

Bought a new Mac but can't access wireless networks I used to because their passwords are saved on my old pc.

Can WiFi names and their passwords be exported from a Windows 7 PC and imported to a OSX Yosemite?

Can this be done locally (without sending the settings over the internet), e.g. via USB?

I don't know how to write scripts or code but I'm tech savvy - please elaborate if you have a complex solution.

Comment: @Ramhound You can use `netsh wlan show profiles name=profilename key=clear`

Comment: @DavidPostill - I was not aware of that command.

Comment: @Ramhound You can learn something every day ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - When will I learn to walk away from certain types of users, before I bang my head against my desk out of frustration, and have to explain to my boss why its broken?  * I should point out, that I left "it" intentionally vague, in a lame attempt to be funny.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can you export WiFi settings from Windows 7

Two ways:

1. Use [Netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
2. Use [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) by [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/).

Notes:

- This will allow to export or see the wireless keys for stored wireless profiles.
- I don't use OSX so I don't know how you would import the keys.

---

#### [Netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) solution:

1. Retrieve a list of wireless profiles:

   ```
    netsh wlan show profiles
   ```
2. Retrieve the detailed profile for a specific wireless profile:

   ```
    netsh wlan show profiles name=profile_name key=clear
   ```

Notes:

- `key=clear`. When specified, it means that if a key is present in the profile and the user has **administrative privileges** on the local computer, then the plain text key is displayed as part of the profile.
- In the following example, the Profile name and Wireless key have been censored.

Example:

```
F:\test>netsh wlan show profiles

Profiles on interface Wireless Network Connection:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    <None>

User profiles
-------------
    All User Profile     : censored


F:\test>netsh wlan show profiles name=censored key=clear

Profile censored on interface Wireless Network Connection:
=======================================================================

Applied: All User Profile

Profile information
-------------------
    Version                : 1
    Type                   : Wireless LAN
    Name                   : censored
    Control options        :
        Connection mode    : Connect automatically
        Network broadcast  : Connect only if this network is broadcasting
        AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks

Connectivity settings
---------------------
    Number of SSIDs        : 1
    SSID name              : "censored"
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
    Vendor extension          : Not present

Security settings
-----------------
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Security key           : Present
    Key Content            : censored
```

---

#### [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) solution

> WirelessKeyView recovers all wireless network security keys/passwords
> (WEP/WPA) stored in your computer by the 'Wireless Zero Configuration'
> service of Windows XP or by the 'WLAN AutoConfig' service of Windows
> Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows Server 2008.
>
> It allows you to
> easily save all keys to text/html/xml file, or copy a single key to
> the clipboard. You can also export your wireless keys into a file and
> import these keys into another computer.
>
> <kbd>[image]</kbd>

...

> **License**
>
> This utility is released as freeware.

Source [WirelessKeyView v1.70 - Recover lost wireless network key](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)